# Instantiating Classes from a Collection of Types

Tags: c#, types, state

Alright, this is going to take some explanation, so here goes:

I'm making a Finite State Machine for a video game where the states are objects that derive from a State base class. Since the states are objects, each has to be instantiated before it becomes the current state. Each state can have sub-states (which still just derive from State) that can be entered and this is where I'm having a problem. I need to be able to store a collection of the Types of each sub-state. For a concrete example, here is how I'm envisioning this working (I realize there are bad practices in this code, but it is simply an example of the goal, not code I intend to use directly):

```
public abstract class State
{
    private Type[] subStates = new Type[0];
    private State currentState;

    public GoToSubState<T> () where T : State, new()
    {
        if ( subStates.Contains(T) )
        {
            currentState = new T();
        }
    }

    //...
}

public class StateOne : State
{
    public StateOne ()
    {
        subStates = new[] { typeof(SubStateA), typeof(SubStateB) };
    }

    //...
}

public class SubStateA
{
    //...
}

public class SubStateB
{
    //...
}
```

Now, while this more or less works, it's not type safe. Since `subStates` is an array of Type, there's no guarantee they derive from State. One work around is to use a register method that can enforce a base type at compile time:

```
public abstract class State
{
    private List<Type> subStates = new List<Type>;

    public RegisterSubState<T> () where T : State
    {
        subStates.Add(T);
    }

    //...
}

public class StateOne : State
{
    public StateOne ()
    {
        RegisterSubState<SubStateA>();
        RegisterSubState<SubStateB>();
    }

    //...
}
```

but this is slightly less attractive. Is there some other way to accomplish my task? Ultimately, all I really need is to be able to set a collection of Types, but in such a way that they Types are guaranteed to derive from State at compile time.

Comment: But if subStates has a type that doesn't derive from State, it doesn't matter because subStates is private and you are enforcing that T : State on the GoToSubstate() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is really the most elegant way to do it.  You're getting the compiler to enforce the restriction you want, while recording only the types you want.

The alternative is to store *instances* of states inside each state.  Then you can expose your collection as containing `State`s instead of `Type`s.  But maybe this isn't amenable to your application.

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping a clever tricked exists that I don't yet know about. Something akin to List<typeof(State)> would be great. Regarding keeping a collection of instances: I'm trying to avoid that, as there can potentially be a very large number of states and I don't want them sitting eating up memory when not in use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a class which inherits from `List<Type>` and overrides the Add function so that type safety is enforced (no back door where the user can call Add directly instead of using your register method). So basically;

```
public class StateList : List<Type>
{
     public override void Add(Type t)
     {
         if (typeof(t).IsSubclassOf(typeof(State))
         {
         }
         else
             throw new InvalidArgumentException();
     }
}
```

Then in the state class you would simply have a `StateList` property rather than a `List<Type>` property. My sample code might require a little tweaking but I think the concept holds. Note, you'll also have to override `AddRange` and another methods that put new objects in the collection.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement that the solution be enforceable by the compiler.

Comment: @CSJ I don't know what you mean, there's the potential for an exception to be thrown at runtime if the calling code attempts to add a Type that isn't a subclass of `State` but there is no way to enforce that at compile time. The OP's code doesn't do it and your answer doesn't propose an alternative. This goes at least a little bit further than the OP's code by overriding the Add methods which his list will expose as public methods. If your list will only work with Types that inherit from State it's better to throw here than down the line when you try to operate on the list.

Comment: The OP's `RegisterSubState` approach does do it, and is the approach I would recommend.  Incidentally I agree with your comment that it's better to throw early.

Comment: @CSJ I don't think either solution is ideal; `RegisterSubState` enforces type safety for that method but the calling code can just do `subStates.Add(typeof(String));` which will cause exceptions down the line. In either case it's going to require documentation to explain what's acceptable because there's no compile time panacea for this.

Comment: This is a good point @evanmcdonnal. I may combine the two solutions or do some 'read only' voodoo to prevent messing with the list after the constructor is done.

Comment: If the `subStates` collection is private (which it is), then the OP is made in the shade.